# What's the correct academic reference for CGAL's Min_sphere_of_sphere algorithm?

Tags: c++, cgal

I'm using CGAL's `class Min_sphere_of_spheres_d<>` and would like to provide the appropriate academic reference describing the algorithm implemented. However, the documentation at
http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Bounding_volumes_ref/Class_Min_sphere_of_spheres_d.html doesn't provide that. Is that perhaps because there is no academic article describing the algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you mention has a citation:

**[MSW92]**     J. Matoušek, Micha Sharir, and Emo Welzl. A subexponential bound for linear programming. *In Proc. 8th Annu. ACM Sympos. Comput. Geom.*, pages 1-8, 1992.

Comment: I have seen that too, of course. But (1) I couldn't find (and verify) that article and (2) it seems only to refer to a meta-algorithm used as a driver of the real method.

Comment: The article is easy to find with Google:
http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/emo/PublFiles/SubexLinProg_ALG16_96.pdf

Comment: That article is **not** the one referenced by CGAL. It is another article, published later, with the same authors and title. According to a footnote, the former is a preliminary version of latter. So, this seems okay.

Comment: The first one is probably an article in the proceedings of a conference, where the second one is the long version of the same article, for a journal issue.